# How to pop-up a calendar inside an ASP.NET Datagrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, calendar

How do I pop-up a calendar inside an ASP.NET + C# Datagrid?

Comment: What's the exact problem you have? Please specify in more detail.

Comment: i am created a Web page,in that i m put the Datagrid,
my last column name in the Datagrid is Submission Date,
when i click on that column in the any row  it should popup Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

You could just make it a text field, and then use one of many javascript libraries for calendars/datepickers.

Here is a list of 50 of them, with ratings and some basic info. You'll need one marked "Standalone" if you don't want to used any other javascript libraries, or you don't know what one of those is.

http://marcgrabanski.com/article/ultimate-list-of-datepickers

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a TemplateColumn for a Submission Date text control and place an AJAX CalendarExtender in with it, this will do all the javascript for you.

See the below site for some useful tutorials on how to get started with AJAX and the Control Toolkit.

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx